# Validate JSON Multidimensional

Tags: javascript, json, validation

Is this written correctly? Is there a better way to write it? This is similar to the real data I am working with and I want to ensure that I'm nesting the objects or arrays properly in the JSON file.

```
var data = [
    {
        "department": "IT",
        "jobs": {
            "title": {
                "programmer": [ 
                    { "skill": "PHP"  },
                    { "skill": "Ruby" }
                ],
                "systems analyst": [ 
                    { "skill": "requirements gathering" },
                    { "skill": "problem solving" }
                ] 
            },
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking if the data design is good or if the syntax is valid?  By the way this is not JSON, it's a JavaScript object literal

Comment: The `data` array is not closed.

Comment: @torazaburo in javascript the `;` isn't as necessary to close variables. But its still good practice, to always close lines with `;` regardless.

Comment: I'm saying the closing `]` is missing! Also, if this is actually intended to be JSON, and not just an object literal, then the `var data =` part is of course invalid.

Answer (score 2):

try to validate it with JSON Lint

http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some major accessibility issues in your "`title`" section of your literal object.

```
{
    "department": "IT",
    "jobs": [
        {
            "title": "programmer",
            "skils": [
                {
                    "skill": "Ruby"
                },
                {
                    "skill": "PHP"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "systems analysis",
            "skils": [
                {
                    "skill": "problem solving"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is much easier to loop over;

```
var MyList = jQuery('<ul></ul>');
for(var x = 0; x < data.jobs; x++) {
    var new_job = data.jobs[x];
    MyList.append('<li>' + new_job.title + '</li>');
    // and so fourth ...
}
```

Comment: Why not just `"skills": ["Ruby", "PHP"]`?

Comment: @torazaburo that too, I was just going off the original scheme in the question, using `{}` could be helpful for each skill, if he wants additional details.